# Recreating failing input value for QuickCheck from a seed

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

When a QuickCheck test fails, sometimes I need to walk through the code in ghci (or stack repl) to analyse the problem. So the first thing I do is recreate the failing input. Now QuickCheck prints out the failing input (using `Show`), but sometimes re-creating the input from this is difficult or impossible. For example, the type in question might not implement `Read`. Or it might be a really complex type which requires lots of types in order to recreate it, and tracking down the modules that export those types, and manually importing them into the repl is a hassle.

**So I'd like to be able to recreate the failing input from the seed**, which is also reported by QuickCheck. It looks like `unGen` in Test.QuickCheck.Gen is designed for this.

> ```
> unGen :: QCGen -> Int -> a
> ```
>
> Run the generator on a particular seed. If you just want to get a
>   random value out, consider using generate.

But `unGen` takes two input parameters. I'm guessing the second one is the seed. How do I recreate the `QCGen` parameter? Here's an example I tried where the seed was -4346962096583255693. `unGen` doesn't seem to like a negative seed, so I must be doing something wrong.

```
λ> (unGen arbitrary) (mkQCGen 0) (-4346962096583255693) :: ImprintEmptyBrainTestData 
ImprintEmptyBrainTestData (*** Exception: Negative exponent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`quickCheckResult`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.12.4/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:quickCheckResult) (or `quickCheckWithResult`) to run your tests. In case it returns a `Failure`, the `usedSeed` and `usedSize` fields have the `QCGen` and `Int` values you need to pass in the `Args` to `quickCheckWith`.

Comment: Could you do an example? (or an syntactic example of the solution)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a package [quickcheck-with-counterexamples](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/quickcheck-with-counterexamples) where properties can capture generated values for further inspection if a test fails.